# First time execution was not stopped

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim i as double=2.5
Textbox1.text= convert.tostring(i)
```

I have this type of code in my project.i have issue that when i debug the code at first time and when the cursor reach as textbox1 it's thorow the error that "cannot convert string to double" but after that when i set next statement and again debug the same code it is execute. so what's the issue and how to solve that

Comment: Your question looks horrible. It's like you didn't bother trying at all. With that said, Convert.ToString(i), i.ToString(), and CStr(i) are valid.

Comment: Dim i as double=2.5 Textbox1.text=i.Tostring()  , Dim i as double=2.5 Textbox1.text=Cstr(i). i have also try this code but i faced same issue. i want to know that how it's not working at first time and only works when i redubug the code

Comment: You need to show more code.   The code posted would not have any errors.  You should also post the exact error message as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to adapt your code like this:

```
Dim i as double=2.5
Textbox1.text= i.tostring()
```

Comment: I have done all that things but unfortunately it thrown same error at first time. but at second time of execution it is working properly